# Is there any possible way to create migration with out using rails "generater"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie, learning rails with `Active Record`. Can we create or alter `migration` with out using rails generater??

Comment: create a file under `db/migrate`directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to alter the existing migration without using the generator, there is a hack for it.

In your db, there will be a table named as `schema_migrations`. Remove the timestamp from that particular migration you wanna alter, from that table. Run `rake db:migrate` again with the alterations and the migration will run again.

Comment: Why not just just rake `db:rollback` to undo the last migration, edit it and run rake `db:migrate` to bring it back up? Just curious as the need for the hack?